# How can I limit my sprite update rate?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm creating a small RPG worl with pygame. So far so good, I load my maps with Tiled TMX entity manager, and everything is great. Except one thing. When my main character moves, the sprite animation is going to damn fast and I don't know what to do to avoid that. Here is my update() code :

```
def update(self):
        self.index += 1
        if self.index >= 2:
            self.index = 0
        if self.direction == DIRECTIONS['down']:
            self.image = self.down_anim[self.index]
        elif self.direction == DIRECTIONS['up']:
            self.image = self.up_anim[self.index]
        elif self.direction == DIRECTIONS['left']:
            self.image = self.left_anim[self.index]
        elif self.direction == DIRECTIONS['right']:
            self.image = self.right_anim[self.index]
```

And my keyboard event management :

```
key=pygame.key.get_pressed() 
        try:
            event = pygame.event.wait()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if (event.key == K_LEFT):
                    if angus.direction != DIRECTIONS['left']:
                        angus.direction = DIRECTIONS['left']
                    angus.update()
                    angus.position.x -= 1
                elif (event.key == K_RIGHT):
                    if angus.direction != DIRECTIONS['right']:
                        angus.direction = DIRECTIONS['right']
                    angus.update()
                    angus.position.x += 1
                elif (event.key == K_UP):
                    if angus.direction != DIRECTIONS['up']:
                        angus.direction = DIRECTIONS['up']
                    angus.update()
                    angus.position.y -= 1
                elif (event.key == K_DOWN):
                    if angus.direction != DIRECTIONS['down']:
                        angus.direction = DIRECTIONS['down']
                    angus.update()
                    angus.position.y += 1
```

I'm using a clock to force 60fps. Is there a way I can tell pygame for example : update the sprite but only if it has been more than 1 second since the last update ?
Thanks

EDIT : Solution :

```
def update(self):
        self.timer += 1
        if self.timer >= self.UPDATE_TIME:
            self.index += 1
            self.timer = 0
            if self.index >= 2:
                self.index = 0
            if self.direction == DIRECTIONS['down']:
                self.image = self.down_anim[self.index]
            elif self.direction == DIRECTIONS['up']:
                self.image = self.up_anim[self.index]
            elif self.direction == DIRECTIONS['left']:
                self.image = self.left_anim[self.index]
            elif self.direction == DIRECTIONS['right']:
                self.image = self.right_anim[self.index]
```

Comment: What I think of is the time.sleep() function. Also, you may want to convert your if-elif loop to dictionaries.

Comment: I think the time.sleep() pause the program and therefore stops every possible action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep a seperate variable in charge of timing whether or not to increase `self.index`.

```
## within __init__
    self.UPDATE_TIME = 60 # or whatever works
    self.timer = 0

def update(self):
    self.timer += 1
    if self.timer = self.UPDATE_TIME:
        self.timer = 0
        self.index += 1

    # unmodified below here
    if self.index >= 2:
        self.index = 0
    if self.direction == DIRECTIONS['down']:
        self.image = self.down_anim[self.index]
    elif self.direction == DIRECTIONS['up']:
        self.image = self.up_anim[self.index]
    elif self.direction == DIRECTIONS['left']:
        self.image = self.left_anim[self.index]
    elif self.direction == DIRECTIONS['right']:
        self.image = self.right_anim[self.index]
```

Comment: Your code is quite wrong because putting the whole condition block under the condition would avoid me to "change" the image even if it doesn't change. Though it worked and that's great, thanks.